# 'Continue' Not properly in loop

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and i'm trying to understand how to use loops, but i can't seem to get continue to work and i'm not sure why. It says i'm not using continue properly but i tried to put it everywhere

```
while True:
    print('Enter a number')
num = int(input())
if num < 10:
    continue
    print('The number is greater than 10')
elif num > 20:
    print('The number is less than 20')
else:
    print("You're getting closer")
if num == 15:
    break
    print('End')
```

Comment: It's not in a loop; your indentation is wrong. Also, the `print` following `continue` will never execute, because `continue` immediately returns to the top of the loop, not after the current `if` suite completes.

Comment: I would suggest looking through the Python docs on [control flow](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Answer (score 1):

Indentation matters in Python; everything in your sample needs to be indented relative to the `while` keyword in order to be included in the body of the loop.

Further, if you check for `15` first, you don't need a `continue` statement; the loop will continue on its own as long as you don't explicitly break out of it.

```
while True:
    print('Enter a number')
    num = int(input())
    if num == 15:
        print('End')
        break

    if num < 10:
        print('The number is greater than 10')
    elif num > 20:
        print('The number is less than 20')
    else:
        print("You're getting closer")
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your identation is in your file as it is on your answer, then your `if` statement (inside of which is your `continue`), is on the same indentation as your `while` statement. You should indent your `if` statement (and all other code which is supposed to be inside of the `while` loop) at least once

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the `if`/`elif`/`else` statement:

```
while True:
    print('Enter a number')
    num = int(input())
    if num < 10:
        continue
        print('The number is greater than 10')
    elif num > 20:
        print('The number is less than 20')
    else:
        print("You're getting closer")
    if num == 15:
        break
        print('End')
```

You you don't, even if the `continue` statement is fixed, you will get an `break outside loop` error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place `continue` after `print` statement, else it will not get printed and skips to the next iteration.

```
while True:
    print('Enter a number')
num = int(input())
if num < 10:
    print('The number is greater than 10')
    continue
elif num > 20:
    print('The number is less than 20')
    continue
else:
    print("You're getting closer")
if num == 15:
    print('End')
    break
```